# Is the name Mahdiya allowed for baby girl?

Tags: naming

Kindly provide the meaning for Mahdiya and is the name of Mahdiya is allowed for baby girl in Islam?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Mahdiya is the feminine word for Mahdi meaning 'rightly guided by Allah' and is used by Muslims parents to name their child. It is an Islamic name so it is allowed.

It is a Quranic name of that means 'well-guided' and 'under the guidance of God' and it is indirectly mentioned in the Quran but it's root (H-D-Y) is mentioned in the Quran and it is a root for one of the 99 names of Allah (Al-Hadi- The Guide).

Here is an example of it :

"Those who believe and do good deeds will be guided by their Lord because of their faith. Rivers shall flow at their feet in the Gardens of Bliss. (Quran 10:9)"

Source: http://quranicnames.com/mahdia/
http://www.babynames.co.uk/names/mahdiya/